# Textbox auto fill in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, autofill

Can anyone tell me how to disable autofill for text boxes in asp.net?

to get a better Idea :

In the Login webpage. When a user provides a username and password there is also a (Remember Me) check box for next time login...  So far, everything is fine.

but the problem appears in the registration form, when the user opens the register page, both fields (username and password ) are filled out with the users name and password used for the previous login.

Does anyone have an idea about this problem?

Note: I have tried these two lines of code in page load event, but it didn't work.

```
txtUsername.Text="";
txtPassword.Text="";
```

I will appreciate every single answer.

Comment: well i'm not posting the answer for you but you should always use txtUsername.Text=String.empty; far better then txtUsername.Text="";

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I will use it in the next parts of my project...
btw do you know how to create a secure login Panel?just a brief description if you don't mind.

Comment: @ReboKoye Use the login control of ASP.NET

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable autofill for the TextBoxes by adding `autocomplete="off"`:

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="txtUsername" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="txtPassword" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="Server" ID="xyz" autocomplete="off" />
```

Or try this In From Tag

```
<form autocomplete="off" ...
```

Answer (score 3):

and for your from :

```
<form id="register" autocomplete="off" method="post" runat="server">
                      ^ THIS ATTR
```